# How to make checkout page 2columns-left on magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, xml

I try to make the checkout page `2columns-left`layout, but i can't.

If i add this code in **checkout_index_index.xml**

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 layout="2columns-left"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

the page is not loading

by default this layout is like this:

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

so if i change **layout="checkout"** to **layout="2columns-left"** the page is not loading

I sucesfull changed the checkout cart page in this way and is working, but not for checkout page.'

Does anyone know how to change checkout page to *2columns-left* layout?

Answer (score 0):

To change the checkout page to 2columns-leftlayout, just change the file

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/page_layout/checkout.xml
```

to

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="2columns-left"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="checkout.header.container" as="checkout_header_container" label="Checkout Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content">
            <container name="checkout.header.wrapper" label="Checkout Page Header" as="checkout_header_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

> NOTE : css changes are need afterwards to style the checkout page.

Comment: I advise against editing the file mentioned, you should extend this file and make your changes in your theme/module. Do not edit the core files (files inside the vendor directory) as you will likely lose your changes.

Comment: i just overwrite in theme but is not working anyway

Comment: Yes sure..do not change directly the core. file. I supposed i didn't have to mention that. You have to copy that file under your theme folder and do the changes. I just tried it changing the core file for quick testing and worked fine for me.

Comment: i copyed the file in my theme but is not working. is working for you?

Comment: I just tried it changing the core file for quick testing and worked fine for me.

Comment: @NikoK You'll be surprised at the number of people who still edit the core, I've seen answers accepted that were advising to edit the core :(